What's the best georeferencing setting to select to georeference an irregular projection?
So, I am essentially planning to use georeferencing to shift a neogene North America map to the rough shape of modern North America. Now, I generally use Polynomial 3 when georeferencing because it shifts finds the projection you are using and warps it to fit the projection on the map, accordingly but since this isn't really shifting one projection to another it won't work as well, so I am looking for a setting best just warps the raster to fit the projection on the project directly.

"Best" Questions are inherently opinion-based and discussion-oriented and therefore off-topic for our Focused question/Best answer model. Please [Edit] the Question to ask an answerable question.

Affine Transformation should arguably be your best option, since Affine allows for georeferenced skewing, which works best with Robinson Projections (Assuming that's the projection of the Neogene map you are working with).
Try it out and use Longitudinal lines as your reference as opposed to oceans, POI's and other raster features.
